# Meteor.methods() unexpected behaviour when using $push and db.update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have this code to update an entry:

```
function updateList(listTime) {

    var firstList = Project.find().fetch()[0].list; // returns a list
    var nextElement = (firstList[firstList.length-1] + 50); // value of last + 50

    Project.update({name: "List 1"}, {$push: {list: nextElement}});
}
```

and I call it from:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateList: updateList,
});
```

becouse I'm using a python ddp client and needs to be this way.

The problem is that nextElement doesn't really increment the sequence on my list. Imagine that my list was [50,100,150,...], if I call updateList, it becomes [50,100,150,150,150,150...] and so on... And it's supposed to become [50,100,150,200,250,300...].

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Why do you +50 if you want +1?

Comment: It was an error elsewhere in my code. Sorry guys, and thank you for the answers

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by making nextElement `+1` instead of `+50`.

```
var nextElement = (firstList[firstList.length-1] + 1);
```

Note that listTime will become the last element in the list. So if you run `updateList(20)` the list will become `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20]`. If you then call `updateList(2)` it will become `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 21, 2]` and so on.

I'm not sure what listTime is supposed to do but if you wish to add `last int + 1` to the list:

```
function updateList() {
    var firstList = Project.find().fetch()[0].list;
    var nextElement = (firstList[firstList.length-1] + 1);

    Project.update({name: "List 1"}, {$push: {list: nextElement}});
}
```

This will result in:

```
Project.find().fetch()[0].list
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

updateList()
Project.find().fetch()[0].list
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

updateList()
Project.find().fetch()[0].list
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.
Forget the second update.
And the "plus 1" increment is just an example. What I really want is a "plus 5" increment

Comment: I edited the post to be more coherent

Comment: I can see the number incrementing but then reverting...

Comment: Mm, not sure to be honest. Are you sure that you're fetching/updating the correct Project document? Or perhaps there is other code in your application that resets your list.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It must be a trick with update() or methods() or even Meteor.call() that I'm not aware of..